# Yii2 different form fields on create and on update scenario

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

In my Model I have created different scenarios. I have one form which is rendered bu both create and update method. The form fields are as follows

**Form.php**

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

 <?= $form->errorSummary($model, $options = ['header'=>'', 'class'=>'pull-left errorDiv']); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'user_fname')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control']);?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'user_lname')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control']); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model,'user_email')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control']); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'user_password_hash')->passwordInput([]); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'user_password_hash_repeat')->passwordInput(['class'=>'form-control']); ?>
            <?php  $items = ArrayHelper::map(SimAuthAssignment::find()->all(),'item_name' ,'item_name');?>
            <?= $form->field($mode, 'item_name')->dropDownList($items,[]);?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

On using update scenario I want only my email, firstname and last name to be rendered from the form.

```
 const SCENARIO_REGISTER = 'signup';
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';

 public function scenarios()
{
    return [

          self::SCENARIO_REGISTER => ['user_email', 'user_password_hash', 'user_fname', 'user_lname', 'agree','!user_password_hash_repeat','required'],
          self::SCENARIO_CREATE => ['user_email', 'user_password_hash', 'user_fname', 'user_lname','!user_password_hash_repeat','required'],
          self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['user_email', 'user_fname', 'user_lname', 'required'],
    ];
}

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'sim_user';
}
```

And in my controller update method I am using scenario as below code.

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $model->scenario = SimUser::SCENARIO_UPDATE;
       // var_dump($model->scenario); exit();
        $mode = \app\modules\auth\models\SimAuthAssignment::find()->where(['user_id' => $id])->one();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $mode->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'mode' => $mode,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I want to get only the email, firstname and lastname form fields to be rendered in the form when I edit. I want to ignore the others fields in the form when I edit. What am I missing here? Thanks!!

Comment: What mean  "get only the email, firstname and lastname form fields when i update"  .. where .. in  controller . after submit .. ?  you have also teh other fileds .. ? please explain better ..

Comment: I mean to say , When I edit the user, it should render only the email, firstname and lastname fields in the form.

Comment: You are working with a model .. and the model contain all the fields ..

Comment: The answer you had posted worked for me.. That is what I wanted,, thanks a million!

Comment: You are referring to the comment or the answer? if your refer to the answer  please rate  it ..

Comment: And if my answer is right please mark it as accepted ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an activeForm with all the inputField .. so all the fields are submit .. if you want only email, firstname and lastname 
you should use another view with onnly these fields

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

 <?= $form->errorSummary($model, $options = ['header'=>'', 'class'=>'pull-left errorDiv']); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'user_fname')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control']);?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'user_lname')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control']); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model,'user_email')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control']); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The scenario then check only the fields you have ruled and the submit return only the data you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $model->isNewRecord functionality

```
    if(!$model->isNewRecord) {
          echo $form->field('Your-field')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to hide some input elements depends on your form scenario.

So, this can be easily achieved using the following code:

```
<?php if ($model->isUpdating()) { ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_fname')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_lname')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_email')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($model->isRegistration()) { ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_password_hash')->passwordInput([]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_password_hash_repeat')->passwordInput(['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
    <?php $items = ArrayHelper::map(SimAuthAssignment::find()->all(), 'item_name', 'item_name'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($mode, 'item_name')->dropDownList($items, []); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

According to this, add the following code to the form model:

```
public function isUpdating() : bool {
    return $this->scenario === self::SCENARIO_REGISTER;
}

public function isRegistration() : bool {
    return $this->scenario === self::SCENARIO_UPDATE;
}
```